# PHP gdlib or imagemagick lighting normalization between 2 images

Tags: php, imagemagick, image-manipulation, gdlib

Is there any simple way (tool, script) to, having 2 images of exactly same scene in different lighting conditions, normalize them so they would appear like they would be made in same conditions?

I have read about some histograms and how this normalization should work, but can't really find any real (non theoretical) solution.

Comment: Any chance you could give us a few images to play with?

Comment: Yes, but give me some time, please :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a simple way ... (non theoretical) solution?

There's plenty of implementations out there, but the really good ones are patented, and under lock-n-key by companies like Fuji, Nikon, Polaroid, & etc.

Your going to have to do the math, and/or mimic other opensource works.

PHP's Imagick offers methods like [Imagick::contrastStretchImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.contraststretchimage.php), and [Imagick::linearStretchImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.linearstretchimage.php) to align, trim, and shift histograms. If you really are attempting to adjust the lumanuis, [Imagick::colorMatrixImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.colormatriximage.php) can be used to rebuild/alter an image's color-balance. Take a look at Fred's [whitebalance](http://fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/whitebalance/index.php) script for example.

Comment: The problem is that it's not about white balance, but about image to image  comparation and normalization. That is a bit different problem (at least in toolset or script implementation).